VBA Underscore Escapes
I'm trying to decipher an identifier in a MS Access VBA code snippet I have been given, and in particular am curious in which contexts an underscore in an object name must be escaped when that object name is incorporated in an identifier.
So, e.g., a control may be named cboSector_ID (for better or worse).
In that case, however, the identifier is [Lookup_cboSector__ID], i.e., the underscore in the object name immediately before ID is doubled in the identifier.
I presume (a) an underscore is a special character in this context and (b) doubling the underscore is its escape mechanism.
So, the first question is when this syntax is indicated (required).  Perhaps put otherwise, when and why does an underscore in an object name become a special character (and what happens in that context if not escaped)?  Documentation of VBA special characters is haphazard and incomplete and I've uncovered nothing on point, apart from a few thin and terse suggestions in the context of VBA interface classes.
The second question, if anyone knows, is what kind of object the identifier references, and how it can be utilized other than in Form.OrderBy.
